# OSPF Routes not exporting

Tags: ospf, juniper

I have two routers (layer 3 switches to be honest: ex4200 and ex2200). I have zeroized both of them before starting this config. I have set up ge-0/0/12 on one as unit 0 family inet address 10.0.0.1/24 and 10.0.0.2/24 on the other and connected them. I set up ospf on both devices as follows: set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/12. run show ospf neighbor tells me that I have a Full state, so the routers have paired. Next, I want to export some routes from one device to the other, but none of the routes I have on either device are being exported. Have I skipped some step?

Comment: What did you do to advertise the routes? Did you put the interfaces of the routes into OSPF? You should show your configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSPF Feature Guide for EX4600 Switches > [Juniper OSPF Overview](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos16.1/topics/concept/ospf-routing-overview.html)

### CLI Quick Configuration

To quickly configure an OSPF interface on a broadcast or point-to-point network and to allow the inbound OSPF into the interfaces that are active, copy the following commands, paste them into a text file, remove any line breaks, change any details necessary to match your network configuration, copy and paste the commands into the CLI at the [edit] hierarchy level, and then enter commit from configuration mode.

```
set interfaces ge-0/2/0 unit 0 family inet address 10.0.0.1
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.1 interface ge-0/2/0
set security zones security-zone Trust host-inbound-traffic protocols all
set security zones security-zone Trust host-inbound-traffic system-services all
set groups global security policies default-policy permit-all
set security zones security-zone Trust interfaces ge-0/2/0
```

Comment: That looks like config for a SRX, not an EX series switch.